# Eclipse throw NullPointerException when running JUnit test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

The version of my JDK is **7.0**.
The version of my Eclipse is **eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64**.
The version of JUnit is 4.4.

My code is as follows:

```
package nn;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Ofin {

       @Test
       public  void  show(){
           System.out.println("cx");
       } 

       @Test
       public  void  show2(){
           System.out.println("cx2");
       }       
}
```

---

My question is that when I select the name of a method (for example select `show`) and run JUnit test, Eclipse throws `NullPointerException`.

However, when I select the name of method **and its brackets** (for example selecting `show()`) it is ok, I can see the result on console. But why?

My code is so simple that it can't have a syntactic error.
I use older version of Eclipse, but versions in years after 2014 all have this problem.

Comment: There's nothing here that would throw that NPE.  Can you paste the full stack?

Comment: @Makoto I think it's an IDE problem, when you select the method, right-click and 'run test'. Still, stack trace would be nice.

Comment: I agree with Makoto. Nothing throws a NPE. You should upgrade your Eclipse version and JUnit too and try again. However, testing without assertion(s) is not a test.

Comment: thinks for you help！~it  really has a NPE，but I have solved it yesterday afternoon.
I write is in my answer in details。

Answer (score 0):

I search and find somebody say it may be the version of `JUnit` causes this problem.then,I  try it.
I abandon to add external `JUnit` jar(The version is 4.4)
and write `@Test` in text editing area,then use `alt + /` let IDE to add `JUnit4` library，after this，everthing is OK.

**It's not a IDE problem，maybe a conflict between inner version in eclipse and the external version.**